# ASP.NET MVC save image to SQL Server database and retrieve

Tags: sql-server, image

I have a situation where image is currently saved on IIS Server and displayed..

Currently this HTML fragment is saved into the SQL Server database:

```
<img class='img-responsive' src='../resources/files/70382f46-a254-49c2-b296-9c10b2d6d152.jpg'  width='871' height='503'/>
```

This expects that the image exists on IIS server.

Now I want to save the image itself in SQL Server.

Is there any way I can save something like

```
<img class='img-responsive' src="Actual Image"  width='871' height='503'/>
```

If so what should be the datatype in SQL Server be, any example or links?

Thanks
JM

Comment: The datatype should be varbinary(max). Surely you can look at google and find thousands and thousands of examples and/or tutorials. Sadly, this is off topic as you asking for somebody to point you to a tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

you can go with either of these ways :

- save in database as binary (varbinary or so ) and convert it to hex value to show in your html page like this :

  `img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBrkJggg==" alt="Base 64 encoded!"`

read this : ([Converting from hex string to varbinary and vice versa](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqltips/2008/07/02/converting-from-hex-string-to-varbinary-and-vice-versa/))

- Or using filstream in SQl server ( [Enable and Configure FILESTREAM](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqltips/2008/07/02/converting-from-hex-string-to-varbinary-and-vice-versa/) )

you may take a look this article as well : [Storing Images in DB - Yea or Nay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay#3756)